# Rails / Prawn Image From Active Storage Color modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, rails-activestorage, prawn, minimagick

I'm looking for your help regarding an issue i have with on Rails with Prawn(Gem for PDF) when adding an image from Active Storage. When using the image on the app there is no issue but when i add the image to a PDF the colors are different. I've tried to look into minimagik command but i cannot figure how to solve the issue.

There is an example of the problem :

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhtzJ.png)
[Image output in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJg8u.png)

Thank you all for your help

I tried to use MiniMagik but i couldn't find the right command.

Comment: It looks to me like [this issue](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/783) is part of what's happening. When I used `convert` as detailed in that thread with your image, it was still a little off, but a lot closer.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help. I've tried it but unfortunately if it's working for this image, when apply to process to other images, the results is completely different. Here is what i'm trying to do : I'm doing the website for an ART Gallery and they have pictures of images with a lot of different colors ( sometimes red/ blue/green ) . I'm storing the image with active storage and the images rendered fine online. But one feature is to be able to download PDF with the image inside. It works fine for most of the them, but the ones with a lot of colors are not converted normally